# Current URL and if statement

Tags: php

I have a multisite based on wordpress. The sites use the same theme and are located under the same domain. And I want them to display some code depending on with site it is.

So I have something like this

```
<?php 
 $currentUrl = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
 if ($currentUrl == 'http://example.com/institution/') {
   do something
 } else {
  do something different
}
?>
```

now this works when ever I'm on `http://example.com/institution/` or `http://example.com/institution2/` (and sub pages of institution2 `http://example.com/institution2/contact` ) but when I go to sub pages of institution for example: `http://example.com/institution/gallery` the code isn't working. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Well, you need to compare a substring or better the beginning of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` only. Your current `==` comparison means _exact_ equality. But those different paths are not identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As arkascha already mentioned in his comment you are checking for [equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) of the provided url and the expected url. What you really want is to check whether the (from the user) provided url **starts with** your expected url.

You can achieve this by using the [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function.

> stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string
>
> ```
> int stripos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
> ```
>
> *haystack* The string to search in.
>
> *needle* Note that the needle may be a string of one or more characters. If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.
>
> *offset* If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string. If the offset is negative, the search will start this number of characters counted from the end of the string.
>
> *Returns* the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginnning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1. Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

So you can change your code to

```
  if (stripos($currentUrl, '//example.com/institution') >= 0)
  {
    ...
  }
  else
  {
    ...
  }
```

or with inverse logic (check if it is NOT)

```
  if (stripos($currentUrl, '//example.com/institution') == FALSE)
  {
    ...
  }
  else
  {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: The first option works for example.com/institution/ but it's not displaying anything for example.com/institution2/ the second example doesn't display anything for both sites. I have changed the >= 0 to != and then it worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$currentPath = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$currentPath = explode("/",$currentPath);

if ($currentPath[1] == 'institution') {
   do something
} else {
  do something different
}
?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good. Please add some explanation to your answer on how it works.